# Xamarin Forms entry text doesn't return a number

Tags: c#, forms, xamarin, math, text

I'm very new to programming. I'm trying to store entry text in float variables, then calculate basic percentage and show it below inside a label. In place of a variable inside a label it prints NaN. If I use integers instead it says that I'm trying to divide by zero which tells me that the text read from entry returns nothing.

What could be the reason for that?

```
public partial class GoalTrackerPage : ContentPage
{
    float goal = 0.0000f;
    float done = 0.0000f;
    float progress = 0.0000f;


    public GoalTrackerPage ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();

        g1EntryGoal = new Entry();
        g1EntryDone = new Entry();
        g1PrBar = new ProgressBar();          
    }

    private void add1_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GoalStatusLabelView();
    }

    private void GoalStatusLabelView ()
    {          
        progress = done / goal * 100.0000f;
        g1StatusLabel.Text = "The Goal is at " + progress;
    }

    private void g1EntryGoal_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        goal = float.Parse(g1EntryGoal.Text ?? "0");
    }

    private void g1EntryDone_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        done = float.Parse(g1EntryDone.Text ?? "0");
    }
```

Comment: `progress = done / goal * 100.0000f;` i think it will be `progress = done / goal * 100.0000;`

Comment: you are not assigning the `Text` property of the `g1EntryGoal`or `g1EntryDone` entries anywhere

Comment: Can u debug and print the value of `g1EntryGoal.Text` in console?

Comment: Alex, what about:
    goal = float.Parse(g1EntryGoal.Text ?? "0");

Comment: Fahadsk, debug prints 0 for both strings assigned to entry.Text after I enter a number and hit enter.

Answer (score 0):

```
{          
    progress = done / goal * 100.0000f;
    g1StatusLabel.Text = "The Goal is at " + progress;
}
```

The result is basically just zero, and since it is carrying a double value, it will return NaN at g1StatusLabel.Text.

Perhaps this could shed a little more info on dealing NaN result.

[Double.NaN Field](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.nan(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Jasvinder Singh, why is it zero if I enter a number into the entry?

Comment: Hmm, what happens when you debug on g1EntryGoal.Text and goal? What data are you seeing in it?

Comment: prints [0:] for both entries.

Comment: So that means there is something wrong with your data capture, since it prints 0 instead of the value you've added.

Comment: I&#39;ve double checked and triple assigned the text property. Even using more vars then I need just to make sure. The EntryGoal.Text is still 0 no matter what I enter. Btw, I've only assigned numeric keyboard for both entries.

Comment: How would I properly capture the data from entry?

Comment: I would usually use an object class and/or data layer but its an overkill here, I don't have an environment right now to debug this, if I do get an update I'll post it here.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! Since I've been assigning text property inside the event "Text Completed" I should've used different syntax.
The proper syntax for this case would be:

var g1DoneText = ((Entry)sender).Text;

instead of standard:
   var g1DoneText = G1EntryDone.Text;